# When digitizing, polygons are inverted

Tags: qgis, polygon, digitizing, vectorization

I need to use QGIS to digitize my images. My images are scanning electron microscope (SEM) images of rocks. I am interested in analyzing the pore space in the images. Here is the steps I follow:

1. I use imagej to threshold the images; convert the gray scale image to a black and white image (0s an 1s).
2. I use QGIS to digitize the black and white image to create a shapefile of polygons that I can use for further analysis. The polygons represent the pores in the images.

I ran into a little problem while following these steps. When I digitize my images using raster-conversions-polygonize, the polygons come out inverted. 
Any ideas as to why this is happening?

PS: I noticed that the origin of the image changes when I load it into QGIS form the bottom left corner to the top left corner. I couldn't change it to check if it is the source of error.

Comment: You'll need to 'georeference' the images. Is it possible to post a link to one of the images? N.

Comment: Can you show us one of the B&W images.  It may be that your expectation is inverted :)